# The numbers 49/1; 49/2...49/97 are written on the board.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, induction

The numbers $\frac{49}{1},\frac{49}{2},...,\frac{49}{97}$ are written on the board. Every time we make a move we erase two numbers from the board ($a$ and $b$) and instead we write: $$2\cdot ab-a-b+1$$ After $96$ moves there is only one number left, what is it?

Been struggling with this one for a while now. I thought maybe it's useful to count the sum or the sum of the reverse numbers. Or it could be done with induction but I didn't come up with anything. Thanks in advance  Also I really don't know how to tag this so please help

Comment: As a first step in looking for a solution, you could take three (arbitrary) numbers $a,b,c$ and remove them in the three different possible orders, confirm whether they indeed give the same result and see whether that result can be simplified. Do the same with four elements as well. See what happens. Also note that$$2ab-a-b+1=ab+(a-1)(b-1)$$which might help with simplification.

Comment: Arthur thanks I'll try that

Comment: What is not clear to me is, are `a` and `b` integers in the denominator OR the fractions in the sequence?  (Or does it not matter?!)

Comment: Fractions in the sequence

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$a*b=2ab-a-b+1=\frac{1}{2}((2a-1)(2b-1)+1)$ i.e. $2(a*b)-1=(2a-1)(2b-1)$. Then, use induction to prove that $2(a_1*a_2*\ldots*a_n)-1=(2a_1-1)(2a_2-1)\cdots(2a_n-1)$ and that is why it also does not depend on the order of terms in $a_1*a_2*\ldots*a_n$ Finally, the result is:

$$a_1*a_2*\ldots*a_n=\frac{1}{2}((2a_1-1)(2a_2-1)\cdots(2a_n-1)+1)$$

In our case, we want to calculate $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{97}{1}\frac{96}{2}\cdots\frac{1}{97}+1)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{97!}{97!}+1)=1$

Comment: Your decomposition of $2ab-a-b+1$ is much better than my $ab+(a-1)(b-1)$.

Comment: Should it not be $$a_1*a_2*\ldots*a_n=\frac{1}{2}(2a_1-1)(2a_2-1)\cdots(2a_n-1)+\frac12?$$

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks! A pair of brackets was missing, fixed now.

Comment: I don't quite understand why do you write $$a*b=2ab-a-b+1$$?

Comment: @FoorgyInfifcio It just makes "$a*b$" a shorthand for "the number you write down when you remove $a$ and $b$"

Comment: Ah, ok got it thanks

Comment: Finally wrote it down. Thank you so much!